# Eclipse warning in attribue type with search value

Tags: html, eclipse, warnings

In Eclipse, how can I get rid of unnecessary warnings like:
Undefined attribute value search

```
<input id="xx" name="xx" type="search" value="" />
```

this is one example

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="find" type="search" id="find" value="0" />
    </body>
</html>
```

if I just put

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

warning disappears

if I make the same change in complex file, warning does not disappear and many others appear due to incompatibility with html5

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in the current Eclipse in a HTML 5 file. Either the warning is correctly displayed in a non HTML 5 file, or your Eclipse is pretty out of date. If this does not help, please make sure to tell how to reproduce this issue in the current Eclipse (in your case you have to tell, which file with which content has to be opened with which editor of which plugin of which version).

Comment: Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
Build id: 20210910-1417

Comment: Fresh installation or upgraded? Which editor?

Comment: Upgraded. Editor? default

Comment: Which one will be the default editor depends on things you missed to say.

Comment: all editors: jsp, text, web. File is jsp

Comment: Did you really verify it's for all editors by creating a new _General > Project_, creating a new file in this project containing the mentioned single line only? I took my time and tried different things, but I can't reproduce it: see my first comment. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I supplemented the request with further information.
Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

The warning is displayed since `<input type="search" ... />` is [**invalid in XHTML**](http://xstandard.com/en/articles/xhtml-reference/input/#input-attributes).

Avoid it or **better use HTML5** (even though this warning can be deactivated in *Project > Properties: Validation > HTML Syntax* by setting *Attributes > Undefined attribute value* to *Ignore*).